# Collapse tool bar layout is not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to display hotel image and hotel room types in recycler with parallax effect.I want collapsible image with Recycler view. I got it but collapse is not working.What I did wrong in this.
Please help me..on this...
My code is here

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/hotelDetailsRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/hotelHeaderImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

my java file is

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hotel_details);
    Toolbar toolBar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolBar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    hotelHeaderImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.hotelHeaderImage);
    mVolleySingleton=VolleySingleton.getsInstance(this);
    mImageLoader=mVolleySingleton.getmImageLoader();
    mRecyclerview=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.hotelDetailsRecyclerView);
    mLinearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerview.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(findViewById(R.id.app_bar_layout), "");
    collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("YG");

}
```

Please tell me what I did wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

To make it collapsible you don't need java code, just the xml. I changed the `layout_height` of `hotelHeaderImage` to `match_parent` and the `layout_height` of `app_bar_layout` to `256dp` (for example), and it worked.